# Partition for iTunes

Tags: itunes, bootcamp, partition

I have a Mac with bootcamp and unfortunately i see myself using bootcamp far too often because I'm a developer and VS2013+SqlServer is way too demanding for my 8gb ram... but i use iTunes a lot... so i was thinking, if i create a Fat32 partition and put my iTunes folder there so i can point both my OSX iTunes and my windows iTunes and be able to not only read but write (app updates, new songs, etc...) will it work?!? or maybe the folder structure is different or something like that?!?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No you cannot. I resorted to every resource and i don't know why but it seems that win8.1 messes up the partition (ExFAT) rendering it unusable beyond repair... either that or Mavericks messes it up when copying itunes backup to it...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same folder for Mac and Windows versions of iTunes. I would recommend use the exactly same version though. Here is more info on how use it through the network: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070424081346722. It's the same logic, but you will be using the same local folder instead a network shared one.